# Code optimization causes null reference exception when using PeekMessage

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, peekmessage

I'm using the game loop discussed in this gamedev.stackexchange thread:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67651/what-is-the-standard-c-windows-forms-game-loop

Everything is working great if I'm using Debug build type, but when I go to do Release, I get a null reference exception.  It looks like it only happens if I enable code optimization.  This is a barebone example that does the same thing.  The form is totally blank, there are no buttons/controls on it in this example.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sharp8
{
    public partial class DebugForm : Form
    {
        public DebugForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Application.Idle += GameLoop;
        }

        private void GameLoop(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (IsApplicationIdle())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Game Updates/Rendering!"); 
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct NativeMessage
        {
            public IntPtr Handle;
            public uint Message;
            public IntPtr WParameter;
            public IntPtr LParameter;
            public uint Time;
            public Point Location;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool PeekMessage(out Message message, IntPtr window, uint messageFilterMinimum, uint messageFilterMaximum, uint shouldRemoveMessage);

        private bool IsApplicationIdle()
        {
            Message result;
            return !PeekMessage(out result, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, the exception is said to happen in external code inside forms.dll, and it's throw after my Application.Run("etc") that starts this form.  The stack trace isn't really helpful, it's just the Application.Run and a bunch of external code.

I'm not sure what is causing this, but I know it has something to do with calling PeekMessage, because if I comment out the subscription to the Idle event the error does not happen.

As a side question, why do I need to declare the "NativeMessage" struct here?  It doesn't seem to cause issues if I cut it, yet every example of using this game loop includes it.

Comment: can you cut the code down to a short compilable example that exhibits the behaviour?

Comment: Done, this is the slimmest example that does what I mean.  The Console.WriteLine is where my emulator update/rendering would be.

Answer (score 3):

While [@shf301's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21693182/1768303) correctly explains how to solve the problem with `PeekMessage` in your code, I'd recommend to not use `PeekMessage` at all for this purpose, as it comes with some unneeded overhead. Use [`GetQueueStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644940%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead:

```
public static bool IsApplicationIdle()
{
    // The high-order word of the return value indicates
    // the types of messages currently in the queue. 
    return 0 == (GetQueueStatus(QS_MASK) >> 16 & QS_MASK);
}

const uint QS_MASK = 0x1FF;

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetQueueStatus(uint flags);
```

For some more details, check my [answer on "Winforms updates with high performance"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21654436/1768303).

Comment: This is very interesting, and in an emulator no performance gain should go overlooked.  Thank you for providing an alternative solution, I'll be looking into the link you provided intently.

Answer (score 1):

The `out` on `PeekMessage` should be `ref` instead.  `PeekMessage` doesn't allocation a message structure for you, it fills in a message structure that you pass in.  The different would be that a `ref` parameter must be initialized before being passed into the method call, where an `out` parameter does not need to be initialized.  You'll see that when changing `out` to `ref` the compiler will force you to add a `new` call to initialize `result`.

In playing with this I found that just adding the call to `new Message()` to initialize `result` and leaving the parameter as `out` was enough to prevent the crash.  I would assume that when the code is optimized no memory for `result` is allocated causing the call to `PeekMessage` to fail.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PeekMessage(ref Message message, IntPtr window, uint    messageFilterMinimum, uint messageFilterMaximum, uint shouldRemoveMessage);

private bool IsApplicationIdle()
{
    Message result = new Message();
    return !PeekMessage(ref result, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Upon closer inspection this actually doesn't fix the issue.  It compiles fine, but still throws the nullreference exception at runtime.  I tried leaving it as "out" and init the object beforehand and also trying via ref.  I still get the same crash.