# Async /Await Only Multithreading?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I try to execute a simple code asynchronously with TPL of c#. But not in a separated thread! I want to work only with the main thread and I want that my WPF Application doesn't freeze.

That's way, I don't use the methods Task.Run or Task.Factory.StartNew (they create a new thread). I do that:

```
    private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var someTask = new Task<List<Person>>(() => CreateList());
        await someTask;
        ListBoxControl.ItemsSource = someTask.Result;
    }

    private List<Person> CreateList()
    {
        var list = new List<Person>();
        list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000).Select(x => new Person(x)));
        return list;
    }
```

But after await, it returns never. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: 1000000 items is the way too many, it will frustrate your user. Anyhow, I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21592778/1768303.

Comment: Why do you want this to run on the UI thread anyway? Are you trying to solve some other problem?

Comment: yes, that is a simple example.

Comment: @Ziggy, also think about what may happen when the user clicks the `ButtonBase` button again, while you're still populating the listbox as a result of the previous click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the great benefits of `async-await` in client UIs like WPF is precisely ofloading non UI work (like CPU-heavy taks or blocking I/O) off of the UI thread.

In fact, that's precisely what you want in your hypotetical example.

With the proper use of `async-await`, your code can be as concise as this:

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxControl.ItemsSource = await Task.Run((Func<List<Person>>)CreateList);
}
```

Or, if you are not using CreateList anywhereelse:

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxControl.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            var list = new List<Person>();
            list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000).Select(x => new Person(x)));
            return list;
        }
    );
}
```

And if you don't need to keep the list:

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxControl.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(
        () => Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000).Select(x => new Person(x))));
}
```

Here are a few articles you can read to get up to speed with `async-await`:

- [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)
- [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh873175.aspx)
- [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You have created a `Task`, but you haven't started it.  `await` is waiting for the task to finish, and as you have seen, it never will in this case.

Since you don't want to use a background thread, I'd look into @Noseratio's comment.